# Polynomial of degree n such that w(k)=1/k, compute w(0).

Tags: polynomials

Polynomial of degree n such that $w(k)=1/k$ where $k=1,2, \ldots 2^n$
Compute w(0)

My sketch:

Consider 
$P(x) = x w(x) - 1$

From interpolation we have that 
$P(x) = a(x-1)(x-2)...(x-2^n)$
So I compute a, 
But i have problem with w(0)

Comment: The polynomial $P(x)$ you define is clearly of degree $2^n$ and so $w(x)$ is of degree $2^n-1$.. You should correct your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT

Your method is good.

Equating constant coefficients gives you $a$ and then equating coefficients of $x$ gives you $w(0)$.

$$xw(x)-1 = a(x-1)(x-2)...(x-2^n)$$

Put $x=0$, then $-1 = a(-1)(-2)...(-2^n)$. This means we now know $a$.

The coefficient of $x$ on the LHS is $w(0)$. This must equal the coeeficient of $x$ on the RHS.